# Importing an animation in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, import

So im working on a game and i want to store all image files in an assets folder. But wouldn't it be a pain to import each frame of a symbol's animation? Is there a way to import a single file containing the whole Ball (Ball is an example) animation inside the Ball class? If there is no way to import a single file only, how do you import the images and assign them to each frame of a symbol?

Comment: You should look for sprite sheets, there are some implementation of these, then you can declare one single embed directive for the sprite sheet bitmap, and use parts of that as frames for your animation.

Comment: Any specific link i could use? Because i couldn't find any that helped, also i don't know how to embed anything...

Comment: "embed" about equals "import a file" in this case. The links? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195257/as3-sprite-sheets There are more, of course.